# How to calculate expectation for the variables with given density

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, expectation, density-function

Let $a_i \in\mathbb R^N,\,  i=1,\ldots, N$ and let $x_i, i=1, \ldots, N$ be independent random variables with density with respect to the Lebesgue measure given by $\dfrac{e^{-|t|^q}}{\Gamma(1+1/q)}, \, t\in\mathbb R, q\geq 1$.

My question is how to calculate or, at least bound $\operatorname E\left|\sum_{i=1}^Na_ix_i\right|^q$?

Comment: Isn't it rather $\frac{e^{-|t|^q}}{2\,\Gamma(1+1/q)}$? (cf. [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) if $q=1$, where $\Gamma(1+1/q) = \Gamma(2)  = 1$)